# How do I segment this array according to returned key in Vue JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js

I have the following array which contains 132 action_id's:

```
[ { "id": 1, "project_id": 6, "action_1": 0, "action_2": 0, "action_3": 0, "action_4": 0, "action_5": 0, "action_6": 0, "action_7": 0, "action_8": 0 ..."action_132": 0]
```

This is returned here:

```
progress() {
      return this.$store.getters['progress/getProgress']
    }
```

The `action_` id's are numbered for a particular reason -they all belong to `Tasks`, of which there are 11.

For instance:
`action_1` - `action_3` belong to `Task 1`,
`action_4` - `action_8` belong to `Task 2`,
`action_9` - `action_11` belong to `Task 3`, and so on...

How can I write a JavaScript function that would segment the actions into Task arrays?

So I would have something like

```
Task1: 
  [
    action_1,
    action_2,
    action_3,
  ]`  
`Task2: 
  [
    action_4,
    action_5,
    action_6,
    action_7,
    action_8
  ]`  
`Task3: 
  [
    action_9,
    action_10,
    action_11,
  ]`...
`Task11: 
  [
    action_128,
    action_129,
    action_130,
    action_131,
    action_132
  ]
```

I already know which `action_id's` belong to which `Task` so in my mind I imagine something like:

```
Loop through `progress` {
   if action_1 to action_3 {
     Task1.push
   }
   if action_4 to action_8 {
     Task2.push
   }
   if action_9 to action_11 {
     Task3.push
   }
}
```

What would be the correct syntax to make this happen?

Comment: Can the input array contain multiple objects or is it only ever one? When you say *'and so on...'* it isn't clear what the pattern is: can there be more than 3 tasks and how do you determine which actions belong to which task? What values would you expect in the output arrays? Could you provide a more detailed example of what you would expect that output data structure to look like? I suggest updating the question rather than trying to answer my questions in a comment.

Comment: It seems your actual problem is the datastructure and that's where you should try and solve this. Find a way to better structure your data so it will represent the entities you're working with.

Comment: I've added more detail about what I want to achieve and the relationship between actions and tasks

Answer (score 0):

I assume the `process` is the task object `{ "id": 1, "project_id": 6, "action_1": 0, "action_2": 0, "action_3": 0,  ..."action_132": 0`

```
Object.keys(process).map(key => {
    if (key.includes('action')) {
        const actionNumber = key.substring(7)     // get action number
        if (1 <= actionNumber <= 3) {
             task1.push(process[key])             // push the value of that action to task
        }
        ... for another eondition
    }

})
```